# Is it possible to secure the data of an IOT idevice in an ICS by using MAM?

Tags: tangle

The idea is to add IOT devices to an ICS (industrial control system), send and retrieve the data of these devices through the tangle. 
The data will be sent through the IOT device using MAM and be retrieved by the SCADA system using MAM also. In fact, it comes to deleting the PLC and replacing it by the tangle. 
Could this work? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and prototyped at

https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2018/06/mimic-mqtt-lab-and-iota-mam.html

"IOTA is *the* DLT (distributed ledger technology) for the Internet of Things.
The facility for distributing telemetry from sensors is called MAM (Masked
Authentication Messaging), for details see their blog.

We were able to transfer dynamically changing MQTT telemetry generated
from our Bosch sensor simulation in our MIMIC MQTT Lab sent to the public
MQTT broker broker.hivemq.com, then through IOTA MAM to the IOTA
tangle in real-time.

You can check it yourself at this online IOTA MAM Explorer,   enter this
string..."